# C : printf with only string format as argument

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

```
int main()
    {

       printf("Hello World!");        
       printf("%s");//printing Hello World again why?

    }
```

This code prints "Hello World!" twice. Why is it happening like this?

Comment: I guess you mean `printf("%s");`

Comment: Undefined behaviour. In this case, stuff from the past (the pointer to the string) is used in the present - with a function call expecting an argument that was never given. Answering the question serves no real purpose.

Comment: Because you're experiencing undefined behavior. You happen to be getting the contents of memory by writing bad code. If you do something totally wrong, you shoudn't be surprised when you get some unexplainable results.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%s")` causes undefined behaviour.

Once you have that line in your program, your entire program becomes undefined and could do or not do anything.

Most likely, by complete luck, your stack still contains pointer to the literal string from the previous call so the function still is able to execute correctly.

Comment: "*... by complete [bad] luck ...*"